# android bluetoothsocket receive zero-value bytes?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

Got a problem at receiving bytes from bluetooth socket. I'm trying to send message created by arduino - couple of single bytes values i.e. 0x41, 0x05, 0xFF(...) into my phone with android. It works fine until one of these value is zero (0x00). Transmission hangs until new message comes. Anyone meet with that situation?

My "reader" works in separate thread, processBuffer() do sth with data that should be received:

```
public void run() {
    while(stop == false){
        try {
            bytes = InStream.read(readbuffer);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++){
                Log.d("FRAME", "Read bytes "+readbuffer[i]);
            }
            Log.d("FRAME", "Read number of bytes "+bytes);
            processBuffer(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("BT_debug", "Cannot read bytes");
            Log.d("BT_debug", "iterator: "+iterator);
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using such short messages, you can use an alternate read method which specifies that you want 1 byte at a time. Then you won't get hung waiting for more bytes to arrive.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the problem is on the Android end, and not on the Arduino end?  It sounds a lot like you have some C code somewhere treating the 0 byte as a terminating null, and that seems more likely to be a mistake in your Arduino code than in the behind-the-scene Android native code.

Comment: I'm checking bytes that are send before invoking Serial.println() on Arduino side and there are all data that should be send. This situation is weird so maybe there is some stupid bug here or this setup need something more (?). Gonna check receiving byte after byte as BitBank wrote but imho that won't work.